# Ayuda para ejecutar javascript resultado de transpilar typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Tengo un ***código javascript*** resultado de *transpilar* código **typescript**.

Extracto:

```
define("slider", ["require", "exports", "classes/Slider"], function (require, exports, Slider_1) {
    "use strict";
    exports.__esModule = true;

    function init() {
        // code
        // ...
    };
});
```

Intento acceder al código anterior, pero no se como hacerlo, por ejemplo, con una de las siguiente sentencias en el mismo fichero y después del bloque anterior:

```
init(); // Uncaught ReferenceError: init is not defined

console.log(Slider_1); // Uncaught ReferenceError: Slider_1 is not defined
```

> #### Editado

No se si es un problema con el código o con la generación del mismo. Este es el fichero **tsconfig.json** situado en la raiz del proyecto:

```
{
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "removeComments": true,
        "outFile": "./public/js/slider.js",
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/*",
        "./src/**/*",
    ],
}
```

Comment: Hola! Podrias ampliar la info sobre el problema, ¿que es lo que esperas que el sistema retorne? ¿valores de entrada/salida? o alguna info que ayude a darte una orientacion o una respuesta

Comment: @Cristian Budzicz No hay ningún retorno, se hacen unas comprobaciones y cambios en el DOM de una página HTML que carga el fichero JS. El código se ejecuta si lo copio del ***editor online de TypeScript***: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ Es decir que copio cada clase y el código de llamada a la ventana de TS, eso sí quitando ***export*** de las clases (creo que es necesario en un proyecto TS para las imports), pero hace más complejo el código JS de salida.

Comment: nope, no intentes hacer debug del código traspilado, usa herramientas para hacer debug al typescript como augury